# XML Publisher Parameter Date Formatting

Tags: bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

In XML Publisher template, how can I format the date parameter to `DD-Mon-YYYY` format?

`<?param@begin: p_start_date?>
Start Date -  <?xdofx:substr($p_start_date,1,4) || '-' || substr($p_start_date, 6,2) || '-' || substr($p_start_date, 9,2)?>`

With the above format, my output is `2017-09-18`, expected output is 
`18-May-2017`

I have even tried with `<? xdofx:p_start_date('DD-Mon-YYYY’)?>`, but the output is 
`2017-09-18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the to_date function ? Its documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10091_01/doc/bip.1013/b40017/T421739T481158.htm).